# Different results on applying the same property decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

When I apply a `property` decorator to a method in a class definition, python accepts the version with the `@decorator` but not with the explicit syntax. Following is the code:

```
>>> class Person:
...     first_name = property()
...     def first_name(self):
...         pass
...     first_name = first_name.getter(first_name)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in Person
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getter'
```

This result I can understand - although `first_name` is defined as a `property` object, it is then redefined as a function object which has no `getter` method.
   But then how does the following code work -

```
>>> class Person:
...     first_name = property()
...     @first_name.getter
...     def first_name(self):
...         pass
... 
>>>
```

I have made only a syntactic change but this version gives no error. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you have overwritten the property in `first_name` with a function. Functions do not have a `getter` attribute by default. The `def` is syntactic sugar (sort of) for something like:

```
first_name = property()

# def replacement
first_name = lambda self: None

first_name = first_name.getter(first_name)
```

The second uses the decorator and so `first_name` is what `property().getter(func)` returns. Which is a property.

The normal style for all this though is:

```
@property
def first_name(self):
    pass
```

Which is more or less the same as:

```
first_name = property(lambda self: None)
```

The getter/setter style works because decorator is referenced before the function is assigned to the namespace (in fact when using a decorator, there is no intermediate step where the function is assigned to the namespace).

```
first_name = property()
# this is effectively how the function definition and decorator code is executed
first_name = first_name.getter(lambda self: None)
```

Comment: I know the normal style - I was reading an example in the Python cookbook. What I don't understand is that both the approaches I have stated are equivalent in the syntax but yield different result. When `@` is used, why is there no name clash?

Comment: Because `first_name` as a property is referenced before it is overwritten as the result of the decorator.

Comment: Going by the book, I can have a setter method `@first_name.setter` after the getter. If, as a result of the getter decorator, `first_name` is now a modified method name, then how will the setter syntax work ? `first_name` is now not a `property` object. How does `@first_name.setter` refer to the property object again?

Comment: `property.getter` and `property.setter` both return a property. So long as `first_name` was a property to begin with then there is no issue.

Comment: I guess `first_name` still remains a `property` after the getter is applied.